# Characterization of maximal monotone operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

I found the following theorem:

> Given $H$ Hilbert space and a monotone operator $A\colon H\rightarrow H$, then A is maximal monotone if and only if $\operatorname{Range}(A+I)=H$.

Note that: $A$ monotone (multivalued) means that $\forall u,v \in H$ and $\forall f\in Au, g \in Av$, then $(u-v,f-g) \geq 0$.

Moreover a monotone operator is said to be maximal in the sense of inclusion of graphs (i.e. the graph of A has no proper monotone extension).

Where can I find a detailed proof of this fact?

Thank you in advance, I'm really clueless.

Comment: A bit of context: often we want to solve $A(x) = 0$ for a given function $A$. But if $A$ is a set-valued function, the analogous idea is to find a vector $x$ such that $0 \in A(x)$. Note that $0 \in A(x) \iff x \in (I + A)(x) \iff x \in (I + A)^{-1}(x)$. If $A$ is maximal monotone, then Minty's theorem guarantees that for any $x$ the set $(I + A)^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton. So, $(I + A)^{-1}$ can be viewed as a function from $H$ to $H$. This function is called the "resolvent" of $A$. The inclusion $0 \in A(x)$ is equivalent to $x = (I + A)^{-1}(x)$. You can solve this with fixed point iteration.

Comment: Additional context: where do maximal monotone operators come from? The most important example is the subdifferential $\partial f$ of a lower semicontinuous convex function $f$. If $x \in H$, then $\partial f(x)$ is the set of all subgradients of $f$ at $x$. To minimize $f$, we must find a point $x$ such that $0 \in \partial f(x)$. So set-valued operators and inclusion problems arise naturally in convex optimization.

Answer (score 3):

This result is known as Minty's Theorem. A modern reference and proof can be found in Bauschke & Combettes' book, volume 2, Section 21.1 (Theorem 21.1)